# Regular Expression for CSV that has Quotes and Backslashes for the Entries

Tags: java, regex, csv

I'm trying to find a regular expression that works with CSV files (with double quotes around the values) where the values can contain any characters. The expression I'm using right now is (in Java so the backslashes are escaped):

```
",(?=(([^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*\"([^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*\")*([^\"\\\\]|\\\\.)*$)"
```

The problem I'm having with entries such as "random_value"" or "random_value\".

Additional Info:

```
"000000000000000","","","","email@yahoo.com","random_value""
"000000000000000","","","","email2@yahoo.com","random_value\"
```

Comment: Could you provide examples of possible input and expected output because `expression that works with CSV` is too vague (at least for me).

Comment: Consider using a CSV parse rather than using a complex regex.

Comment: "random_value"" as a value is ilegal csv. however "random_value\"" is legal. Well csv is not a well defined standard :)

Comment: I can help you parse your csv with regular expressions that take into account double quotes used inside values, but they have to be escaped with a backslah. If you don't have that then you have a bigger problem, you should change the way the csvs are generated

Comment: Added some example values, would CSV parse work with formatting issues? This isn't the final file I'll get, so I'll try to make sure values like this aren't in there or are escaped.

Comment: Both lines in your additional info are invalid - they are missing an ending quote. Is that really the state of your data?

Comment: @user2600747: I provided an example of using CSV parser below.

Answer (score 0):

## Description

Well assuming we clean up your source text to include the proper closing quotes, then this expression will:

- Match all quote comma delimited text
- Capture the leading comma and quote and closing quote, along with the included text into group 0
- Trim off the leading and closing quotes and place that value into capture group 1
- Allow values to contain escaped quote sequences like `\"` and `""`

.

`(?:^|,)"((?<=")(?:[^"]*|\\"|"")*?)"(?=[,\r\n]|\Z)`

[image]

## Example

Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/NSSxdHWcDM

**Sample Text**

```
"1000000000000000","","","","email1@yahoo.com","1random_value"""
"2000000000000000","","","","email2@yahoo.com","2random_value\""
```

**Capture Groups**

```
[0][0] = "1000000000000000"
[0][1] = 1000000000000000

[1][0] = ,""
[1][1] = 

[2][0] = ,""
[2][1] = 

[3][0] = ,""
[3][1] = 

[4][0] = ,"email1@yahoo.com"
[4][1] = email1@yahoo.com

[5][0] = ,"1random_value"""
[5][1] = 1random_value""

[6][0] = "2000000000000000"
[6][1] = 2000000000000000

[7][0] = ,""
[7][1] = 

[8][0] = ,""
[8][1] = 

[9][0] = ,""
[9][1] = 

[10][0] = ,"email2@yahoo.com"
[10][1] = email2@yahoo.com

[11][0] = ,"2random_value\""
[11][1] = 2random_value\"
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Using JavaCSV**](http://www.csvreader.com/java_csv.php):

```
String str = "\"000000000000000\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"email2@yahoo.com\",\"random_value\\\"\"";
CsvReader reader = CsvReader.parse(str);
reader.readRecord();
for (int i=0; i<reader.getColumnCount(); i++)
    System.out.printf("Scol[%d]: [%s]%n", i, reader.get(i));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Scol[0]: [000000000000000]
Scol[1]: []
Scol[2]: []
Scol[3]: []
Scol[4]: [email2@yahoo.com]
Scol[5]: [random_value\"]
```